# Heroku migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

**PG**::UndefinedTable:

**ERROR:**  relation **"unitConsumptions"** does not exist

```
: ALTER TABLE "products" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_6c18c32772"
FOREIGN KEY ("unitConsumption_id")
  REFERENCES "unitConsumptions" ("id")
```

Comment: This is not a question ...

Comment: I found the error.It was because I wrote camelcase the model and the class name is not well
Model product
belongs_to unitConsumptions
and class
unit_Consumptions